# Allow specific product codes, alert and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all I'm new to javascript and jQuery.

I've done some research and people say its best to do whitelist than blacklist.

So I thought of allowing only paste/scan/write into textarea specific product codes, like:

> 7AHT182019Y00867F03281P
>
> 7AHT182019Y00293F0281P
>
> 7AHT182019Y00672F021543P

18 is week, 2019 is year, 867 product number, and 3281 is product quantity number.

And while scanning, write or paste product code two times into textarea it gives alert `7AHT182019Y00293F0281P this product code already exists in textarea`.

I've tried filtering, indexOf, and each event handlers..

Started with turning textarea value to array and split it and use indexOf handler.

This code says 10 digits must be numbers. And it must start with 7,8 or 9. But I want to be more specific:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        validateNumbers();
        $('#mobile_numbers').keyup(function() {
            if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
            }
            this.value = this.value
                .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, "")
                .replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1\n");
            validateNumbers();
        });
    
        function validateNumbers() {
            var value = $("#mobile_numbers").val();
            var numbersArray = value.split('\n');
            var validNumbers = [];
            var duplicateNumbers = [];
            var inValidNumbers = [];
            
            // remove empty elements
            var index = numbersArray.indexOf("");
            while(index !== -1)
            {
                numbersArray.splice(index,1);
                index = numbersArray.indexOf("");
            }
            
            for (var $i = 0; $i < numbersArray.length; $i++) {
                var number = numbersArray[$i];
                if (validNumbers.indexOf(number) !== -1 || inValidNumbers.indexOf(number) !== -1) {
                    duplicateNumbers.push(number);
                } else if (number.match(/[789]\d{9}/)) {
                    validNumbers.push(number);
                } else {
                    inValidNumbers.push(number);
                }
            }
            $("#total").text(numbersArray.length);
            $("#duplicate").text(duplicateNumbers.length);
            $("#valid").text(validNumbers.length);
            $("#invalid").text(inValidNumbers.length);
        }
    });
```

It should start with `7AHT`. Week should be `18` and year should be `2019Y`.

`00867F` is product code which can also be specific, because it doesn't change.

Product quantity is the only thing that changes: `03281P`.

And if you try scanning same product for the second time, it should alert it as duplicate and shouldn't add this product code to textarea.

Comment: Did't get what you meant by `00867F ` will not change. That'll be different for each product, right?

Comment: @DaniVijay so I have job list where is like 3 products so I add 3 matching products 7AHT182019Y00672F, 7AHT182019Y00867F, 7AHT182019Y00293F so these cant change, with PHP I add these parameters for every job list. Week and Year I add automatically with javascript or PHP, I've not thinked through that.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to find out if text starting with specific string (7AHT182019Y00672F) then u can use regular expressions:

```
var res = number.match(/^7AHT182019Y00672F([^\s]+)/);
```

if res is not empty then it matched and result will be contains whole number and piece with just string after fixed part e.g. 7AHT182019Y00672F1234567,1234567 where 1234567 is non fixed part.
U can simply split it by delimiter , :

```
var parts = res.split(",");
var fixed = parts[0];
var nonfixed = parts[1];
```

or just look for position of searching string:

```
number.indexOf("7AHT182019Y00672F") === 0
```

position 0 means that text contains searching string on position 0 so text starts with this string.